# For loop to search for word in string

Tags: java

I can't seem to find the syntax needed for the for loop in this method. I am looking to iterate through the words in the string `suit`.

EDIT: one thing to note is that cardArray is a ArrayList.

```
public String getSuit(int card){
    String suit = cardArray.get(card);
    for (String word : suit){
        if (word.contains("SPADES")){
            suit = "SPADES";            
        }
    }
    return suit;
}
```

Comment: `suit.split("\u0020");` gives you an array of the words.

Comment: I've found it to be more reliable.

Comment: @Legend: Are you really suggesting that `" "` is somehow unreliable?

Comment: I had an incident with a guy once. He was trying to prove that whitespace in Java code doesn't matter to some other guy. He replaced every whitespace character in a group folder with nothing. The program wasn't working for about a week before we found out that we weren't splitting with a `" "`, but rather splitting with a `""`.

Comment: @NPE moral of the story: It is better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use

```
for (String word : suit.split(" ")) {
```

to split on every [space character (U+0020)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20/index.htm).

Alternatively:

```
for (String word : suit.split("\\s+")) {
```

This splits on every sequence of whitespace character (this includes tabs, newlines etc).

Answer (score 4):

Try splitting the string on whitespace:

```
String suit = cardArray.get(card);
for (String word : suit.split("\\s+")){
    if (word.contains("SPADES")){
        suit = "SPADES";            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an enum for suit, and add it to your Card class or something a bit more Object Oriented? You could even have an Abstract class card or an interface card which would let you add what ever logic was needed inside the Card instance itsself instead of iterating doing string comparisons.

However: [String.split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) should work, just choose the appropriate [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Comment: I am using an ArrayList for this assignment so I can get some practice with using Arrays in Java.

Comment: I figured I was just offering a separate approach that might be helpful in the future. For example, you could use an ArrayList<Card> where Card has a enum for suit and a something representing the type of card possibly another enum (ace,2, 3, etc). String comparisons tend to be relatively slow.

Comment: Yeah when I was searching for way to go about it I saw enum as a possible way to go. Anyway I am not going to be calling this method on the program it was just a requirement I had to fill for the Interface as I am already creating the 52 cards with a nested for loop with their suits and ranks as a string in an arraylist.

Comment: With an enum there is a to array method which you could use to iterate through (in two seperate loops one for suit and the other for card type) and populate them that way. But, if you are expected to do it another way dont listen to me, listen to your professor.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is replace the strings that contain "SPADES":

```
public String getSuit(int card){
    String suit = cardArray.get(card);
    if (suit.contains("SPADES")){
        cardArray.set(card, "SPADES");            
    }
    return suit;
}
```

If you want to split the string `suit` for some other reason then see the other answers